# How can I see how HTML that I write will look on the web?

Tags: html

I'm embarrassed to have to ask this, but I'm really new to HTML and web development.

All I want is a simple way to display the results of HTML that I write.  That is, to see how my HTML will look on the web.

I can't seem to open an HTML file in my default browser: Chrome.  I downloaded Microsoft Expression and can type in HTML code but can't find a way to display its results.

I'm not going to write much HTML so I'm looking for a quick, simple approach.

Comment: What do you mean by you can't seem to open an HTML file in chrome? What happens if you try?

Comment: You might want to use [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) as your html editor. Then displaying from there as a local file is easy

Comment: without code, it is not possible to tell where is the problem and solution for it,

Answer (score 2):

Go to https://jsfiddle.net/ to play around with html. It will provide you with warnings if your html is malformed.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an answer to a question that you didn't ask, but is probably what you are looking for:

1. Create a new file, call it `index.html` and make sure that the extension is indeed .html. The extension could be something you don't want if you don't have this checkbox checked on windows.[image]
2. Right click your file and open it in notepad, then paste this inside it:

   ```
       <html lang="en">
           <head>
               <title>Simple Page</title>
               <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
               <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
           </head>
           <body>
               <h1>It works!</h1>
               <ul>
                   <li>Lists work too</li>
                   <li>Lists work three</li>
               </ul>
           </body>
       </html>
   ```
3. Save the file (`Ctrl + S` or `File > Save`)
4. Open your browser (chrome or firefox), and drag the file over your tab bar, or right click the file, choose `open with...` and pick your browser.

You should now see the result of the HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you should be able to open the HTML file in your browser. However, you may see nothing (blank) if your HTML is not correctly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

Save your file with ‘.html’ extension. For example ‘index.html’. And then you can right on the file and select ‘open with’ and choose the browser that you want. Or else you can open your browser first. Then go to File menu -> Open -> Select index.html